# Record Detail Page URL Salesforce community site

Tags: url, community-builder, experience-cloud, detail-page

I have a requirement to show a list of records and by clicking on the selected record the user should be navigated to the record detail page.

As per client needs I did the following:

1. I created a screen flow with a data table which shows all records associated to the logged in user.
2. On the data table page the user can select one record and hit next.
3. In the second screen of the flow I have added a display text as an hyperlink which contains baseURL/siteName/s/pageName/recordId and the page is an object page and on this page I have added a record detail component which takes {!recordId} as an input.
4. When I run this the URL generated is correct.However, it says the following error on the page:(Maybe the page was deleted, the URL is incorrect, or something else went wrong. If you know the page exists but you still can’t get to it, please ask the community administrator for help.)

I am not sure what else I need to do. Help here would be appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]